# .NET: How to Define a Unique Constraint using Entity Framework Core 3.1 Migrations' CreateTableBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating a SQL Server table using [Entity Framework Core 3.1 Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) and utilizing the `MigrationBuilder` and [`CreateTableBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.operations.builders.createtablebuilder-1?view=efcore-3.1) classes, like so:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Example",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            Foo = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false),
            Bar = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Example", x => x.Id);
        });
}
```

I've been able to define a UNIQUE constraint on a single column like so:

```
table.UniqueConstraint(
    name: "Unique_Foo", 
    columns: x => x.Foo);
```

But I need to define a UNIQUE constraint on two columns (ex: `Foo` and `Bar`) and I've not been able to express this in the `columns` argument. (The type of the argument is `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TColumns,object>>`)

**How do I define a UNIQUE constraint on two or more columns using the `CreateTableBuilder` class?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
columns: x => new {x.Foo, x.Bar}
```